# Wrong arrow placement in react-popper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-popper

I am currently trying to fix a bug that appeared when using react-popper. It seems that the `placement` prop is false when there is not enough space above the reference element. In the Screenshot below I can see that the `placement` prop is `top` even though it should be `bottom`. However, it is rather strange that the popper element itself has the correct prop of `bottom` inside the `data-popper-placement` prop.

The arrow in the screenshot should be placed at the beginning of the popover not at the bottom.

[image: wrong prop]

**The JSX**

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {usePopper} from 'react-popper'

import {StyledArrow, StyledBox, StyledBoxWrapper} from './StyledPopover'

const placements = {
  TOP: 'top',
  BOTTOM: 'bottom',
  RIGHT: 'right'
}

const Popover = ({children, content, isPlainHtml, rimless, placement}) => {
  const [referenceElement, setReferenceElement] = useState(null)
  const [popperElement, setPopperElement] = useState(null)
  const [arrowElement, setArrowElement] = useState(null)
  const [showToolTip, setShowToolTip] = useState(false)

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setShowToolTip(true)
  }

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setShowToolTip(false)
  }

  const modifiers = [
    {
      name: 'offset',
      options: {
        offset: [0, 8]
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'preventOverflow',
      options: {
        padding: 10
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'arrow',
      options: {
        element: arrowElement
      }
    }
  ]

  const {styles, attributes} = usePopper(referenceElement, popperElement, {placement, modifiers})

  return (
    <>
      <span ref={setReferenceElement} onMouseOut={handleMouseLeave} onMouseOver={handleMouseEnter}>
        {children}
      </span>

      {showToolTip &&
        content &&
        ReactDOM.createPortal(
          <StyledBoxWrapper ref={setPopperElement} style={styles.popper} rimless={rimless} {...attributes.popper}>
            <StyledBox isPlainHtml={isPlainHtml}>{content}</StyledBox>
            <StyledArrow ref={setArrowElement} data-placement={placement} style={styles.arrow} />
          </StyledBoxWrapper>,
          document.body
        )}
    </>
  )
}

Popover.defaultProps = {
  isPlainHtml: true,
  rimless: false,
  placement: placements.TOP
}

Popover.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Content in the popover.
   */
  content: PropTypes.node,
  /**
   * Reference to the popover.
   */
  children: PropTypes.node,
  /**
   * Remove space between content and border if useful (e.g. content is an image only). Default is {false}.
   */
  rimless: PropTypes.bool,
  /**
   * Add typographic styles for nested content. If content is already completely
   * styled disable this option (e.g. styled-components). Default is {true}.
   */
  isPlainHtml: PropTypes.bool,
  /**
   * Content of the popover
   */
  placement: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(placements))
}

export default Popover
```

**The StyledComponents**

```js
import styled from 'styled-components'

import {StyledHtmlFormatter} from '../FormattedValue/typeFormatters/HtmlFormatter'
import {declareTypograhpy} from '../Typography'
import {scale, theme} from '../utilStyles'

const ARROW_WIDTH = 16

const StyledBoxWrapper = styled.div`
  && {
    pointer-events: none; // prevent flickering of tooltip
    background-color: ${theme.color('backgroundPopover')};
    max-width: 400px;
    z-index: 100000010;
    padding: ${({rimless}) => (rimless ? '0' : scale.space(0))};
  }
`

const StyledBox = styled.div`
  && {
    ${props => props.isPlainHtml && declareTypograhpy(props, 'html')};

    &,
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6,
    p,
    ${StyledHtmlFormatter} {
      color: ${theme.color('paper')};
    }
  }
`

const StyledArrow = styled.i`
  position: absolute;
  width: ${ARROW_WIDTH}px;
  height: ${ARROW_WIDTH / 2}px;
  left: 0;

  &[data-placement*='bottom'] {
    top: ${ARROW_WIDTH / -2}px;

    &:before {
      border-width: 0 ${ARROW_WIDTH / 2}px ${ARROW_WIDTH / 2}px ${ARROW_WIDTH / 2}px;
      border-color: transparent transparent ${theme.color('backgroundPopover')} transparent;
    }
  }

  &[data-placement*='top'] {
    bottom: ${ARROW_WIDTH / -2.5}px;

    &:before {
      border-width: ${ARROW_WIDTH / 2}px ${ARROW_WIDTH / 2}px 0 ${ARROW_WIDTH / 2}px;
      border-color: ${theme.color('backgroundPopover')} transparent transparent transparent;
    }
  }

  &[data-placement*='right'] {
    left: -${ARROW_WIDTH}px;
    top: -6px !important;

    &:before {
      border-width: ${ARROW_WIDTH / 2}px;
      border-color: transparent ${theme.color('backgroundPopover')} transparent transparent;
    }
  }

  &:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
`

export {StyledArrow, StyledBox, StyledBoxWrapper}
```

Comment: Had a similar problem, solved it by following the [docs](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/tutorial/#arrow)  
The problem was I didn't set the css for data-popper-replacement to the main popper element, once I added id="tooltip" to my main popper element(which has the ref={setPopperElement}) and had the correct css it worked flawlessly